# Еще немного про обстоятельства

Tags: пунктуация

Были проведены испытания на стойкость различных конструкционных материалов затворов, применяемых на АЭС российского дизайна, в условиях насыщенного пара.

Применяемых где? На АЭС. Применяемых где? В каких условиях? Как? В условиях насыщенного пара. Два обстоятельства. Надо ли ставить запятую?

Подпитка стенда производится периодически питательной водой 16 МПа/104 °С.

Подпитка стенда производится как? Периодически? Подпитка стенда производится чем? Питательной водой. Надо ли ставить запятую? Мне кажется, нет.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Были проведены испытания на стойкость различных конструкционных материалов затворов, применяемых на АЭС российского дизайна, в условиях насыщенного пара.

Запятая закрывает обособленный оборот, здесь имеется в виду: испытания на стойкость в условиях насыщенного пара.

(2) Подпитка стенда производится периодически, питательной водой 16 МПа/104 °С.

Здесь можно поставить запятую, так как перечисляются параметры подпитки. Без запятой предложение плохо читается.

Comment: Согласна, что предложение плохо читается, но если обстоятельства отвечают на разные вопросы, то можно ли ставить запятую? (Подпитка производится питательной водой периодически - здесь ведь запятая не нужна.)

Comment: Предложение строится так: (1)Подпитка питательной водой (тема) производится периодически (рема). Это правильная структура, которая правильно читается, запятых нет. (2)Подпитка стенда производится периодически питательной водой 6 МПа/104 °С. Где тут тема/рема, в каком месте находится пауза - непонятно. Поэтому нужно ставить запятую. Можно считать, что это не однородные отношения, а уточнение.